# Parse login not working (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have the signup set correctly and one the data is interested it sends it directly to the database. But whenever I run the simulator, it gives me the error "invalid login parameters".

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class SigninViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func signinTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
            } else {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I am using the "user" database on parse so the password column is named "password" and the "myname" is username. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can anybody help guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

The username or password is incorrect. Did you check the user is in existence or not?

If you need to register a new user:

```
let user = PFUser()
user.username = "myname"
user.password = "mypass"
println(user.signUp())
```

then you can:

```
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("myname", password:"mypass") {
    (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if user != nil {
        println("Success")
    } else {
        println(error)
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: do the constants/variables have to be set to "myname" and "mypass"? I have 4 different register fields. fullname, email, username and password. Those are the constants i'm using and those are also what is set in the user class on parse. Do the constants need to be set to myname and mypass?

Comment: No, the "myname" and "mypass" is a variable. I just made a test.

Comment: So for mine, I have constants set to username and password. When I enter PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("username", password:"password") it's telling me I have invalid login parameters and everything is correct when I put it in. I don't have any text fields inserted to my code, do I need that or does it automatically detect that I am entering data from the database.

Comment: So where the username and password comes from? If they come from the `User` table on `Parse`, I think you should go to check them is correct or not.

Comment: http://imgur.com/270Lfe9  ----- that is the user table                                             http://imgur.com/VpmBppQ ----- that is the code for the signin view controller

Comment: You currently have only one user its username is `example`, so instead of using `myname`, you should use `example `. Do you remember the password still?

Comment: But I don't want to hard code it in there, I need the system to let the user login based on what they enter. I cant hard code every username and password, the app needs to let the user login if they enter their correct credentials without me touching the code.

Comment: OK, instead of using `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground("username", password:"password")`, you should use `PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password:password)`, just remove the quotation marks.

Comment: The message "invalid login parameters" is normal, that means your username or password is incorrect. So you can make a test with the `example` and you known password to login, you will not see the message.

Comment: I guess i'm just confused on what to do with the text fields. Do I even need to declare any or? I have them setup as variables and then they become constants that take whats in the text field but I don't think that is working.

Comment: but I do see the message and the credentials are right, It's getting frustrating. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the code.

Comment: Did you use `(username, password:password)` instead of `("username", password:"password")`?

Comment: Did you set the applicationId and clientKey like this:`Parse.setApplicationId("To3HWmbUrAw8WbDXXXXX6R2l08XeT2MbCoRG25Jq", clientKey: "feKkzaJfn8fYMMZakd9LHgxmhX3EQNaKNvmXXXXX")`

Comment: Yeah, I think I may not be doing something right with the test fields, what should I be doing and setting them to?

Comment: Could you share your project on Dropbox?

Comment: My Gmail: zhangao0086@gmail.com

Comment: I invited to share the folder with you.

Comment: Yeah, I saw the folder is empty

Comment: It's currently uploading, itll table a second

Comment: Nah, okay...its uploaded now!

Answer (score 0):

Change password: "mypass" to password: "password"

Comment: I am still getting the error. I changed from "mypass" to password: "password", and I also tryed changing "myname" to "username" because that is the class in the database.